# QCheckBox text padding

Tags: qt5, qtstylesheets, qcheckbox

Is it possible to specify some style sheet properties for text of QCheckBox?

I'm interested in padding first of all...

I see that we can customize ::indicator of check box but I couldn't find any information about text.

Comment: look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html. in the list of properties you'll find the properties supported by QCheckbox. here some working examples: checkbox.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid black; padding: 10px; color: red; spacing: 50px; font: 14pt;')

Comment: I couldn't find any properties for TEXT of QCheckBox in QT documentation.

Answer (score 0):

several text-specific style sheet properties are supported by QCheckBox, e.g. `color`, `font`, `font-family`, `font-size`, `font-style`, `font-weight`, `text-decoration`. 
`padding` is supported too (as padding in the whole widget) and by `spacing` you can set the distance between the checkbox and the text.